# How to use react-native-webview-leaflet?

Tags: typescript, react-native, leaflet

I'm devolopping an app using [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) and [Expo](https://expo.io/). And I want to integrate [react-native-webview-leaflet](https://github.com/reggie3/react-native-webview-leaflet). But when I want to use the tag `WebViewLeaflet` so that I can be able to use WMS with [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/), it underlines the tag then shows this error when I hover the cursor.

> > JSX element type 'WebViewLeaflet' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)
> >
> > Peek Problem
> >     No quick fixes available.

And when I try to run I get this errors

Some times this one

> > Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in
> >     The fact, I have followed the step of installation but nothing work fine for me.

and other time this one

> > WebView has been removed from React Native. It can now be installed and imported from 'react-native-webview' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview

Here is my code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import WebViewLeaflet from 'react-native-webview-leaflet';
import { View } from 'react-native';

 export default class Map extends Component{
    render(){
      return (
        <View>
            <WebViewLeaflet/>
        </View>
      )
    }
}
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
    "expo": "~36.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "^8.0.0",
    "expo-file-system": "^8.0.0",
    "expo-font": "^8.0.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.3.4",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-dynamic-vector-icons": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.26.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-native-webview-leaflet": "^4.3.4",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.3",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.1.5",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.0.15",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "~16.9.0",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.60.23",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.0.0",
    "typescript": "~3.6.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: facing same issue

Comment: @Avinashchavan, did you find a solution?

Comment: Any solution bro? 
@FQuouhadiho

Answer (score 0):

```
import {
  WebViewLeaflet, WebViewLeafletEvents, MapShapeType, Marker, Popup,
  AnimationType, INFINITE_ANIMATION_ITERATIONS
} from 'react-native-webview-leaflet';
```

try to import react-native-webview-leaflet like above

Comment: Does not work for me