# How to use Leaflet in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, leaflet

**Note for people before deleting my topic without even looking at it:**
Of course, I've searched for similar topics on StackOverflow. I could only find one that isn't related to my problem: [How to use react-native-webview-leaflet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59756846/how-to-use-react-native-webview-leaflet)

Hello everyone,

I'm kind of new to React Native (only got to learn navigators and basic components such as Text, View, FlatList, getting my data from my own API, etc) and I didn't learn to React at all as a first step.

Today, I'm a student in a kind of school collaborating with some big science research center linked to my government and I have to make a map app for them. They have one non-negotiable criterion that the project must not use any of Google technology in it. I would like to use Leaflet inside React Native because it allows me a lot of customization about map markers and animations I will need to use.

After spending hours searching for some tutorials, the "biggest" thing I've found is this on Github: https://github.com/reggie3/react-native-webview-leaflet and this person even made a video example of a working project with Leaflet inside React-Native: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IurE-a9P3tY. Despite it being exactly what I'm looking for, I'm 100% confused about how to use it in terms of code (I'm not even able to display the basic background map) and I can't find any real help in form of a tutorial.

**Would any people know something about it? I would be so grateful to you.**

Thanks a lot and if you don't know about it, at least thanks for spending time to read.

Comment: If it's a rule that it can't use Google technology, then Android phones cannot be used, and you can probably do what you want with Apple Maps.

Comment: @Abe No, I mean... Whatever phone can be used, but it must not use Google Maps nor its API or anything related to private companies (so no Apple Maps too).